# Script executes twice but with the same timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having an issue regarding a page loaded with Ajax.
A javascript withing the page loaded somehow executes twice.

Here is the way page is loaded.

```
$(this).html("<img src='loader.gif' />").load(page, parameters, function(response){
$(".dynamic_load").html(response).show();
);
```

Here is the javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 alert("<?=time()?>");
});
```

The script alerts two identical values.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

---

SOLVED:

The problem was unnecessary $(".dynamic_load").html(response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're embedding a PHP generated time value. That value is sent over to your client browser as a fixed value, e.g. your page's source has

```
alert("123456789");
```

in it, which will never change for the lifetime of the page.

Comment: That would be an issue as well. Sorry, I didn't explain my problem clear enough.

Comment: I think that Marc should still get the answer credit for his response, as it is an accurate response to the question. That is a good catch.